# Cognos direct link to report without username or password

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I have Cognos report that i want it when clicking on it's URI to get direct into it without requesting the username and password

any suggestion about methods that could be used ?, i have no problem to make the URI use default username and password but not sure how would be possible

Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Create very special user. VERY limited.
Then add to your repors's link something like

```
   &CAMNamespace=<Your Namespace>&CAMUsername=<Your user>&CAMPassword=<Password>
```

It's rather old method. May not work in modern Cognos

Comment: didn't work told me 
AAA-AUT-0011
 
     Invalid namespace was selected.

Comment: We've got integrated login, so I didn't need the username and password part, but I was getting a namespace prompt that I wanted to get rid of. This helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should allow anonymous access to your server.

Comment: is there another way than that? i just want this specific report

Comment: Anonymous is a risky thing to enable.  You can however control anonymous users with the 'Anyone' user.  Put reports accessible by 'Anyone' in a folder that is just off your root folder in cognos.  Set root with read/traverse for anyone, then set the folder for Anyone reports with read/execute/traverse permissions.  Anyone users will only see this one report.